Clip top or bottom off an .slpk
I want to eliminate some extraneous noise or artefacts from a Scene Layer Package 3D object in ArcGIS Pro (ie, from an .slpk file).
I can use the clip tool to remove anything that is horizontally outside of a polygon that I create using the Clip tool, which is a great start (in recent versions of Pro, the Clip tool will work with .slpk as an input).
However, there are also some artifacts (or noise) above and below the genuine .slpk data that do not get clipped out.  I've tried creating a multipatch that includes the horizontal and vertical portions that I want to keep, but the Clip tool will not accept this as the clip features.
Is there some way to remove noise/artefacts from an .slpk that are above and below the data to keep, but not outside of its horizontal area?
